# After the activity overrides getResources() , how does it take effect for the next running activity?

Tags: android

I found that the first running activity of the app after rewriting `getResources()` will also take effect for the activity that runs later, provided that your phone has a very large font.

E.g: Perform below steps

1. Set the phone font to Big Mac
2. Create two activities named A and B, where A activity overrides `getResources()`, and B does not perform any special operations.
3. First enter B activity and find the font is enlarged
4. Exit the B page and enter the A page. The A page font size is normal.
5. Exit A, then enter B, and find that B's font size is normal.

Then I combed the **source code**, including the activity startup process, I guess where is the configuration cache, the following running activity can be used, but ultimately did not find

This is about A activity ：

```java
@Override
    public Resources getResources() {
        Resources resources = super.getResources();
        try {
            if (resources != null) {
                Configuration newConfig = resources.getConfiguration();
                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
                if (newConfig.fontScale != 1) {
                    newConfig.fontScale = 1;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
                        Context configurationContext = createConfigurationContext(newConfig);
                        resources = configurationContext.getResources();
                        displayMetrics.scaledDensity = displayMetrics.density * newConfig.fontScale;
                    } else {
                        resources.updateConfiguration(newConfig, displayMetrics);
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "A-Activity fontScale :" + resources.getConfiguration().fontScale + " ");
            return resources;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return resources;
    }
```

and  B activity does not perform any special operations.

```
@Override
    public Resources getResources() {
        Resources resources = super.getResources();
        Log.d(TAG, "B-Activity fontScale :" + resources.getConfiguration().fontScale + " ");
        return super.getResources();
    }
```

and the result after run app, about the Logcat:

```
2019-01-28 10:46:22.006  B-Activity fontScale :1.3 
2019-01-28 10:46:22.007  B-Activity fontScale :1.3 
2019-01-28 10:46:26.675  A-Activity fontScale :1.0 
2019-01-28 10:46:26.675  A-Activity fontScale :1.0 
2019-01-28 10:46:29.818  B-Activity fontScale :1.0 
2019-01-28 10:46:29.818  B-Activity fontScale :1.0
```

So I am very confused, how does android work internally, let the setting of `getResources()` of the previous activity take effect for the next one, personal guess is handled in `ActivityStack`, but can't be sure, I hope to give pointers, thank you very much.

Comment: I'd imagine that Android passes the current Resources onto the next Activity, when calling `startActivity()`. Try `getApplicationContext().startActivity()` instead. Is the font still changed?

Comment: Will still take effect, it is doubtful where the source code is processed

Answer (score 1):

Activities in the same application will share **the same Configuration** by default.

If you debug your app you will find `A.getResources().getConfiguration()` return the same `Configuration` instance as `B.getResources().getConfiguration()`. Thus after you modify the `Configuration` in A, it will also influence the `Configuration` in B.

Try to replace `Configuration newConfig = resources.getConfiguration();` with `Configuration newConfig = new Configuration(resources.getConfiguration());`

For more details see source code `ResourcesManager.updateResourcesForActivity`.